# Delphi ANSI and UTF8 Filename

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm creating a program to organize my files (Delphi 7 at Windows 10).

This is my routine to get files:

```
procedure GetAllFiles(mask: string);
{type
  TFileName = type UTF8String; }
var
  search: TSearchRec;
  directory: string;
  fn : string;
begin
  directory := ExtractFilePath(mask);
  // find all files
  if FindFirst(mask, $23, search) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat

      // add the files to the listbox
      Form1.StringGrid1.Cells[0,Count] := IntToStr(Count);
      fn := (search.Name);
      Form1.StringGrid1.Cells[1,Count] := directory + search.Name;
      //Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(directory + search.Name);
      Inc(Count);
    until FindNext(search) <> 0;
  end;
  // Subdirectories/ Unterverzeichnisse
  if FindFirst(directory + '*.*', faDirectory, search) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if ((search.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) and (search.Name[1] <> '.') then
        GetAllFiles(directory + search.Name + '\' + ExtractFileName(mask));
    until FindNext(search) <> 0;
    FindClose(search);
  end;
end;
```

My routine is working, but sometimes there is problem with the name of files. Example:

Filename with windows explorer:
**37 Far★East Movement - Like A G6.mp3**

Delphi is showing:
**37 Far?East Movement - Like A G6.mp3**

I believe that the problem is: Delphi is working ANSI, but the name is UFT8. I figure out pasting the filename at Notepad++.

Comment: File names are Unicode. Delphi 7 does not support Unicode out of the box. your best choice is to install Tnt Unicode controls: https://github.com/rofl0r/TntUnicode and use the Unicode versions of `FindFirst`/`FindNext` etc... and use Unicode controls for the UI (`TStringGrid` does not support unicode).

Comment: Good solution!  :-)  I pretty sure that I will have to redo my program and use WideStrings, right?

Comment: I think it would be a better to upgrade if possible. Unicode support was introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: I would like to upgrade, but I didn't know how to reduce EXE file and some components I heard that there are some incompatibilities... I mean I need more time to move to new plataform. best regards